# How do I get the CURRENT height of a div that changed since the page loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, height

#### What I Want

To determine the height of the .results div that is accurate based on its CURRENT content.

#### Background

As I navigate through my website, the results div is updated with dynamic content based on searches, etc. I am able to get the height of the results div, but it's only the initial value that I can get.

#### Code for Updating the div

```
$results.unbind();
$results.empty();
$results.html(newContents);
```

#### What I've Tried

Note that I print out the values so I can check it in firebug.

```
var $results = $('.results');          /* Prints out: */
console.log($results.height());        /* 18          */
console.log($results[0].scrollHeight); /* 18          */
console.log($results[0].clientHeight); /* 18          */
console.log($results.css('height');    /* 18px        */
console.log($results.attr('height');   /* undefined   */
```

The height extends well past the bottom of the page, so 18px is definitely not accurate. How do I get the real value?

#### Possible Solution?

ryanulit helped me figure out that .height() SHOULD work properly for what I'm doing. So that led to me thinking that there's some problem with events being processed properly. There are many places in the application that return false rather than calling event.preventDefault(). The problem is that when you return false, it also calls event.stopPropagation() in addition to event.preventDefault().

#### Update

I didn't find anywhere with return false that seemed to affect height. However, I did find out that setting the height directly in the html with style="height:0px;" updates the height properly. I'm not sure what else to try, so I'm currently stumped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into the [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) function of jquery.

Here's a jsfiddle to show it is actually changing: http://jsfiddle.net/EvybH/2

**Update**

The `height: 0px;` made me think so I tested in the fiddle and updated: http://jsfiddle.net/EvybH/3/.

If you set a specific height in your css, it looks like the .height() property will always return that value.  Check the fiddle.  You can set `min-height: 18px` if you want to give the div a default height and then allow it to expand.

Comment: That is the first thing I tested in my 'What I've Tried' section.

Comment: Can you show the actual code of how you update the .results div and then try to get the height again?  I did exactly that in my fiddle example and it seems to get the new height just fine.  Also, what browser are you using just in case that may be causing a problem?

Comment: I updated my post with the code I use to update the div. Also, IE7+ and Firefox3.6+ are the browsers I've tested.

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle.  Go to the fiddle and see if the value for height actually changes for you.  My code is the exact same as yours and is working on IE and FF.  Also, for the record, you don't need that .empty() call there.  In this case .html() will clear and add the new html for you at the same time.

Comment: You're right. The jsfiddle behaves properly. I need to see if there's something funky happening with my application...

Comment: I almost always use .preventDefault() as it will normally just stop the exact event I want to stop (i.e. If I want to take over a click event).  I'd need to see the rest of the code to see if a return false is breaking something, but is it possible that you are stopping whatever event is actually changing the HTML and thus the height is always the same when you go to check it again?

Comment: I looked everywhere, and I can't find where return false would be causing a problem. Also, I found out that if I put style="height:0px;" directly into the div's html, then it uses that as its height rather than 18px. But I still can't update it... Any idea what else I could try?

Answer (score 0):

As both the previous posters have said, .height() should be working, however in the case of it not working I believe calling

```
.height(currentElement.height).height()
```

will return a refreshed height (although very hacky and probably discouraged).

Edit: currentElement is the element with dynamic height

Comment: I tried printing out $results.height($results.height).height() and it still gave me 18. Is there something I'm missing?